# Label html quebra texto - ajuste com Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, div

Quando abro minha página no desktop fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando no celular, fica desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="qtdpessoas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantas pessoas junto com você da sua família frequentarão o culto de Vila Aricanduva?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control" name="qtdpessoas" id="qtdpessoas" required="required">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">Apenas eu</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7 ou mais</option>
              
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Eu gostaria que ficasse igual ao celular mesmo abrindo no desktop, visto que no desktop ele amontoa a descrição da label toda na esquerda.

Estou usando bootstrap, estou com dificuldade em ajustar isto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova as classes "col-sm-2" e "col-sm-10".

Com essas classes você está dizendo para o label ocupar duas colunas do grid e o input ocupar 10.

O ideal é você colocar os elementos dentro de uma DIV e setar quantas colunas essa DIV vai ocupar.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-12">
      <label for="qtdpessoas" class="control-label">Quantas pessoas junto com você da sua família frequentarão o culto de Vila Aricanduva?</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="qtdpessoas" id="qtdpessoas" required="required">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">Apenas eu</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7 ou mais</option>
              
         </select>
   </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Te agradeço pela ajuda! Deu certinho !